# validate json with entity class

Tags: java, gson, jsonb

I have three classes like this :

```
public class User {
    private String username ;
    private String password;
} 

public class Profile extends User {
    private String name ;
    private String family ;
    private String age ;

}

public class AnotherProfileType {
    private String name ;
    private String family ;
    private String age ;
    private User user ;
}
```

and also i have a json string like this :

```
{
  "name":"Andy",
  "family":"Bypass",
  "age": 33,
  "username" : "andmand"
}
```

and another json like this :

```
{
  "name": "Andy",
  "family": "Bypass",
  "age": "33",
  "user": {
    "username": "andmand"
  }
}
```

Note : you can see json has not password field . (This is only a example)
now i want to know which class is equivalent to this json .
we know first json matched by Profile class and second json matched by AnotherProfileType class . but how can validate (Understand) that ?

**Update :**
I need a code like this :

```
Object o = gson.fromJson(json,Object.class);
if (Object instanceof Profile) {
 // Do somethings 
}
```

Object do not work in this example .
I want validate and match json to class with data structure.

Comment: What did you try so far? Provide your code so we can fix what you are having problem with.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/processing-json-with-jackson - This says how we can match a json against Java classes. If the mapping fails, it is considered that the json does not match with your java class. But the libraries may be different and also you cannot check the instanceof JSON object with some other object.

Comment: no , this not fix my problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good answer :
[Map Json By Interface](http://technology.finra.org/code/serialize-deserialize-interfaces-in-java.html)